# MySQL Update statement error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1093

I have two scripts, one for the Insert, and another for Update.

My update button script is using the latest inserted Id, and goes on something like this:

```
Update tblsurvey
set WouldLikeToBeSeenOnSite = 'sadffas'
and DislikedOnSite = 'asdfsadfsadf'
and OtherNewsWebsitesRead = 'asdfsadfa'
and LikedOnOtherNewsSites = 'asdfsadfas'
and IPAddress = '172.16.0.123'
and DateAnswered = current_date()
where SurveyResponseId in (select max(SurveyResponseId) from tblsurvey);
```

Apparently, the "where" clause generates an error:

```
1093 - you cant specify target table 'tblsurvey' for update in FROM clause.
```

Is there any other way in which i could use the latest inserted ID of the same table i am updating?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wait a second. why are you using AND to delimit SET claus elements? it must be comma separated.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use the **same table** (in this case, table tblsurvey) for both the subquery FROM clause and the update target.

Its illegal to use same table for updating/deleting and subquery for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations.

Comment: well, since i cant do anything about this, i decided to just create another sp which gets the last inserted id.. thanks anyway. :)